# How can i speed up Downloading with parse?

Tags: android, caching, parse-platform, local-database

I am implementing album of pictures android application with Parse.
So it's very important to download pictures very quickly.
The size of thumnail pictures i saved are around 15~20kb and normal pictures are around 150~200kb
I thinks these sizes are not so big 
However, when i tried to download 10 thumnail pictures once , it would spend more than 7s.
And downloading normal picture is also so slow.

As i know, the file server of parse is located to US.
 i am testing my application in Korea so i think the reaons of the slow is that server is located the place which is so far from korea.
Is there any solution to improve performance for downloading?

I am going to use cache strategy but it's not the solution for downloading at first.
And for improving performance after the first try, i could implement caching with parse local database.
As i know, parse support 10mb disk for saving local data.
What will happen if i save files more than 10mb??

After all, i am gonna summarize my questions as below

1.Is there any solution to improve performance for downloading from parse server?
2. What will happen if i save files more than 10mb to parse local database??

Comment: You should separate image cache from Parse and try using a third-party-library such as Picasso or Glide instead.

Comment: Actually, I used Picasso but I couldn't local disk cache so I've made mind up to use parse local database.

Comment: What i mean is that I can't modify the duration of caching with Picasso

Answer (score 0):

It looks, that main issue here is not app side, but place, where are files, and with this we cannot help a lot (if problem is with speed, we won't do anything, if problem is latency, then we can speed up with downloading few files at the same time. But as you wrote, that downloading normal is also slow, then it is about speed).
If you have control over server, then I suggest you using CDN solutions (like for example CloudFront from AWS), that will help a lot.
Even if you don't have control over server - I'm quite sure, that you can setup CDN anyway, and as source give this server in US, and it should help you. Maybe not in development phase (as here there will be just single calls, and CDN server will have anyway to fetch data), but then during TTL time these files should be fastly downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you happen to use Parse? I tried to use CDN  but I've found out that I can't do with Parse. What i'd like to know that is whether there is any solution for speeding up or not. As you said, the main problem is the place, it looks that I can't improve at all......